# What is the format of remote queues' address

Tags: msmq

Our MQ service will be moved to outside of local server. I can see current destination queue address as ".\Private$\eventQueue".

What is the **format of remote address** for sending messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776346%28WS.10%29.aspx):

```
Private queues are accessible only by Message Queuing applications
that know the full path name, the direct format name, or 
the private format name of the queue, as follows:

* Path name:ComputerName\private$\QueueName.
* Path name on local computer: \private$\QueueName.
* Direct format name:: DIRECT=ComputerAddress\PRIVATE$\PrivateQueueName.
* Private format name: PRIVATE=ComputerGUID\QueueNumber.
```

See [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778392%28WS.10%29.aspx) for more on queue names. One thing to watch out for is that it's not possible to tell if a remote private queue is transactional or not, and if you post with the wrong transactional option set the message is discarded.

Comment: If you hav still problem check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272330/sending-message-to-message-queue-on-my-machine-error-invalid-queue-path-nam

Answer (score -2):

You can't access private queues remotely (that's why they're private). You can use the following queue name to access *public* queues, however:

```
FormatName:DIRECT=OS:<machine>\<queue>
```

(This works with the .NET library, I'm not sure about the native library)

Comment: Not so, private queues can be accessed remotely if you know they're there.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the difference between private and public is that public queues are published to the Active Directory, while private ones are not.