# Sending message to message queue on my machine.....Error "Invalid queue path name"

Tags: msmq, message-queue

I am sending a message to a pretty standard message queue that I have created on my machine running Windows Server 2008 R2.

```
QueueName:
directionsTest
MachineName:
usernameDev
```

When I attempt to send the message to the queue, I receive the error. :

> Invalid queue path name.

Where I am perplexed is that I am actually sending this message via an SSMS query window, we have stored procedures that send these messages to queues and we just provide machine name, queue name, and the message.  So, this is basically a saved query that I have used numerous times, in fact I used this exact same query at the end of last week.  Since then I have not changed the query/my machine/ the queue/ and the stored procedure that creates and sends these messages have not changed.  So, I am unsure why this is giving me this error.

I have tried just about everything under the sun, I have tried creating new queues on my computer and receive the same error.  I have also ensured that everyone has all access to these queues.  Any ideas on what would cause this error to just pop up?  I have scoured the web and I have found no clues as to what could be causing this issue.  (**I have also tested sending to queues on different servers and this works without error)

Thanks for any advice/direction in advance.

Comment: Just to make sure as your description does not mention it. This is not about a clustered server, is it? For clustered servers there are more things to consider, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115232/clustered-msmq-invalid-queue-path-name-when-sending for example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the spelling of your queue name format.

If you use something like

```
YOURMACHINENAME\private$\YourQueueName
```

you should instead try this:

```
FormatName:DIRECT=OS:YOURMACHINENAME\private$\YourQueueName
```

Please note that the first part may be case-sensitive.

Comment: It ended up being part of my string I was feeding in as the message.....must have goofed on the syntax or bumped a parenthesis accidentally.